# Export ExpressionEngine members to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, export, expressionengine, member

I need to export all members from an ExpressionEngine site over to WordPress. How would I go about this? It seems like a daunting task to move them all over, including all their password etc. Any ideas on how to get started? It's fine if the users have to reset their password on logging into the new WordPress site if that's the case. I just can't get my head around it all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a query that will give you results which use the column names and formats that you need for your `wp_users` table. Since the password schemes aren't compatible, you're correct in assuming that users will have to reset their passwords.

```
SELECT
username as user_login,
username as user_nicename,
email as user_email,
url as user_url,
screen_name as display_name,
FROM_UNIXTIME(join_date) AS user_registered
FROM exp_members
```

Run that query on your EE database, export the results (via phpMyAdmin or what-have-you), then import that into your Wordpress database.

Comment: Thankyou Derek, worked perfectly. I ran your query in Navicat, exported as a .csv and used a WP plugin called "import from csv" to successfully import them into WordPress.

Comment: Just curious after you brought over all your users, how did you handle updating their passwords?

Comment: I'd also be interested in the process you had to go through for assigning new passwords to your WP members.

Comment: If you dig into wordPress' guts I'm sure you could find a way to generate new passwords and email them out, but it's easier (and more secure) to have everything reset their password using the standard WordPress procedure.