# Migrating legacy users to symfony2

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, migration, expressionengine

I'm moving from expressionengine to symfony2 and I'm looking for the best way to migrate the user passwords. The goal is to let legacy users log in with their existing credentials, while passwords for new users are created the default way.

I have looked at custom authentication providers and custom user providers and thought about wether or not to create a separate entity for the legacy users, but I don't know what'd be the best way/design to achieve the above.

FYI:

- As far as I can see, expressionengine just encrypts the password
  using sha1 and that's it.
- I am currently using FOSUserBundle.

Can anyone advice me on a solution?

Comment: I think the best solution is to re-import all users into `fos_user` table. Since FOSUserBundle uses SHA1, passwords must not be the problem.

Comment: I think FOSUserBundle uses sha512

Comment: You can configure the encoder factory to use your favorite hashing algorithm.

Comment: Yep I understand. However, I need to support both users, old and new. I need to know what design to use to achieve this

Comment: Write a script to import old users into the new users table.

Comment: Ok and how would I convert the sha1 passwords to sha512 then?

Comment: You don't have to, you just configure sha1 as the password algorithm.

Comment: Ok but I'd rather use sha512 as the algorithm for new users. So that is why I want to support both.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured it out!

Create a custom encoder and use FOSAdvancedEncoder bundle to select the appropriate encoder.

**1. Create the encoder**

```
    <?php

    namespace Acme\MyBundle\Security\Encoder;

    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;

    class LegacyEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface {

        public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
        {
            // Your Custom encoder logic
            return $something 
        }

        public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
        {
            return $encoded === $this->encodePassword($raw, $salt);
        }

    }
```

**2. Register your encoder as service**

```
services:
    acme.legacy_encoder:
        class: Acme\MyBundle\Security\Encoder\LegacyEncoder
```

**3. Install FOSAdvancedEncoderBundle**

Look here: https://github.com/friendsofsymfony/FOSAdvancedEncoderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

**4. Configure your encoders**

In `app/config.yml`:

```
fos_advanced_encoder:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
        legacy_encoder:
            id: acme.legacy_encoder
```

**5. Implement the encoder aware interface in your User Class**

```
use FOS\AdvancedEncoderBundle\Security\Encoder\EncoderAwareInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser implements EncoderAwareInterface {

  ...

  public function getEncoderName() {

      if($this->islegacy()) {
          return "legacy_encoder";
      }

      return NULL;
  }

}
```

Remember to add a boolean field to administer if a user is a legacy user or not.

That's it.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the thread about [exporting members from ExpressionEngine to Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104019/export-expressionengine-members-to-wordpress) will help you.

I don't see any difficulties other than exporting the results from a custom query to the FOSUserBundle structure.

Important things to remember:

- As [Derek Hogue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174299/derek-hogue) greatly points out on that thread, users will most likely have to reset their passwords
- You will have to understand the both structures **really well** in order to correctly import data

Comment: Sorry that won't work. As I state in my question: `The goal is to let legacy users log in with their existing credentials, while passwords for new users are created the default way.`

Comment: Yes, it will work. You can just keep the hash of each password instead of asking for the users to reset them.

Comment: I have tested it, and it won't. That's because symfony bases the hashed password on a combination of the salt and the plain password. EE just uses sha1 hashed variant of the plain password

Comment: Of course it won't magically work. You are a developer, right? You are gonna have to do some adaption work in order for that to work as expected. You can either change the `security: encoders: FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512` to the correct hash and be happy, or write some custom code to treat the case of new users and old users.