# Export ExpressionEngine Members to Wordpress Users

Tags: mysql, wordpress, expressionengine

I need to export existing ExpressionEngine members and convert them into Wordpress users. There is a previous question that answers part of my problem here:
[Export ExpressionEngine members to WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104019/export-expressionengine-members-to-wordpress)

Unfortunately, I also need to include the custom fields from ExpressionEngine from the member_fields table. Is there a way to merge that information with the primary members fields into a CSV that can then be imported into Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just need to join the member_data table and then get all the columns from there.  If there are particular ones that you want you can whittle this down a little, as written it will dump out all custom member fields.

```
SELECT 
    username AS user_login,
    username AS user_nicename,
    email AS user_email,
    url AS user_url,
    screen_name AS display_name,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(join_date) AS user_registered,
    md.*
FROM
    exp_members m
        LEFT JOIN
    exp_member_data md ON md.member_id = m.member_id
```